# Mercurial: list users that have worked on repository

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial through TortoiseHG. I would like to see what users have worked on a repository. Preferrably just a list of unique user names. However it's not practical to scroll down the (long) list of revisions and noting each name. I could probably solve this with grep but I'm on windows and prefer to avoid installing Cygwin or similar. Is it possible, given these constraints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have PowerShell installed then this does the trick:

```
hg log --template "{author}\n" | Select -Unique
```

It takes two or three seconds for my current repository of about 5500 changesets.

Comment: Use `hg log --template "{author}\n" | sort | uniq` on Linux, *BSD, or Mac OS X.